# Merging objects for RestKit

Tags: restkit

How can I map more than one object to one JSON-object?

Here are my two objects

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@interface Account : NSObject
@property NSInteger id;
@property NSString* secret;
@end
@implementation Account @end

@interface Entry : NSObject
@property NSString* name;
@end
@implementation Entry @end
```

And I wish to map these objects to the following JSON:

```
    /* Goal JSON:
     {
     "id":10,
     "secret":"supersecret",
     "eventName":"Hayooo"
     }
     */
```

First try was using a RKMapperOperation directly:

```
void testMergeMap(){
    Account* account = [Account new];
    account.id = 10;
    account.secret = @"supersecret";

    Entry* entry = [Entry new];
    entry.name = @"Hayooo";

    RKMapperOperation* mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc]
                                 initWithRepresentation:@{@"account":account, @"entry":entry} mappingsDictionary:@{@"account.id": @"id", @"account.secret":@"secret", @"entry.name":@"eventName"}];
    [mapper start];
    RKMappingResult* result = mapper.mappingResult;
    NSLog(@"%@", result.dictionary.description);
}
```

But that crashes, can't really make something of the error.

So, how should I do this?

**EDIT**

I also tried this

```
RKObjectManager* testSimpleMap(Account* account, Entry* entry){
    RKObjectMapping* map = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [map addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
     @{@"account.id": @"id",
       @"account.secret": @"secret",
       @"entry.name":@"eventName"}];

    RKObjectManager* man = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    RKRequestDescriptor* requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:map objectClass:nil rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
    [man addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [man postObject:@{@"account":account, @"entry":entry} path:@"/" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];

    return man;
}
```

But we can't create requestDescriptors without a class, so that doesn't work. But I think it's useful to know what I'm aiming for. If that would work, that'd be great!

Comment: Feel free to edit, please don't edit in such a way it's not copy-and-pastable into an editor anymore. I took care in making it self contained, don't ruin that.

Answer (score 0):

`mappingsDictionary:` should not be a dictionary of plain string keys and values. The keys should be key paths to the items to be mapped and the values should be `RKMapping` instances which describe how to map the data found at the key path.

Generally speaking, if you're just starting out I wouldn't use `RKMapperOperation` directly. I'd look at using `RKObjectManager`. It abstracts you away from inner details like this.

If you want to continue with what you have, check the example [in the docs](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMapperOperation.html#//api/name/initWithRepresentation%3amappingsDictionary%3a).

Comment: I don't want to continue using the RKMapperOperation directly, and am using RKObjectManager in my 'real' app (this is just a small testcase). I just saw this class in the docs and thought it was worth trying out. How should I do this with RKMapping instances?

Comment: Have you used `RKObjectMapping` before? If you have an object manager then I guess so. Just map property names to JSON key names.

Comment: But I can't figure out how to create a mapping such that I can merge the Account and Entry object into one request. That's the problem. The  TUTORIAL.md nicely shows how to get 2 objects from one response with relationships, but how do I send 2 objects in 1 request?

Comment: How complex is your real situation? And does the real `Account` have a relationship to `Entry`? Are they plain objects or managed objects?

Comment: This is exactly like my real situation, they are plain objects. There's no relation in the `Account` object to the `Entry`, they exist independently, but I'd like make the relationship for this one request, without creating a `AccountEntry` that models that relationship.

Comment: Then I wouldn't use RestKit for the mapping, at least not initially. I'd just write a line of code to create a dictionary with those pieces of info. Then either use AFNetworking with the dictionary, or RestKit with the dictionary if you had a bigger tie in.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a third object that models the relationship works, but I don't find it elegant enough.

```
@interface Both : NSObject
@property Account* account;
@property Entry* entry;
@end
@implementation Both @end

RKObjectManager* testRelationMap(Account* account, Entry* entry){
    /* Goal JSON:
     {
        "user":{
             "id":10,
             "secret":"supersecret",
        },
        "entry":{
            "name":"Hayooo"
        }
     }
     */

    Both* both = [Both new];
    both.account = account;
    both.entry = entry;

    RKObjectMapping* accountMap = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [accountMap addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"id", @"secret"]];

    RKObjectMapping* entryMap = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [entryMap addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name"]];

    RKObjectMapping* relationMap = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
    [relationMap addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"account" mapping:accountMap];
    [relationMap addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"entry" mapping:entryMap];

    RKObjectManager* man = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    RKRequestDescriptor* requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:relationMap objectClass:[Both class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
    [man addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
    [man postObject:both path:@"/" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
    return man;
}
```

There's a lot of code needed this way, but it's a solution.